# Why Decorator pattern works with pointers but not references?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, decorator

I just learned about the decorator pattern and tried to write an example that uses the code. The example is about beverages and some condiments. Inside the Decorator I have a **reference variable** to a beverage. The beverages available are `Decaf` and `Espresso`. The condiments available are `Soy` and `Caramel`. If I define a `Decaf` with more than one `Caramel` for example, the result I get is just a Decaf with one decorator. So define `Caramel`->`Caramel`->`Decaf` gives me `Caramel`->`Decaf`. Defining `Caramel`->`Soy`->`Caramel`->`Decaf` works fine. Defining `Caramel`->`Soy`->`Caramel`->`Caramel`->`Decaf` gives me `Caramel`->`Soy`->`Caramel`->`Decaf`. Long story short, I can't have two or more condiments of the same type right one after the other. They become only one condiment. If I use pointers it works fine.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "Decaf.h"
//#include "Espresso.h"
//#include "SoyDecorator.h"
//#include "CaramelDecorator.h"

class Beverage
{
public:

    virtual std::string GetDescription() const = 0;
    virtual int GetCost() const = 0;
};

class CondimentDecorator : public Beverage
{
public:

    Beverage& beverage;
    CondimentDecorator(Beverage& beverage) : beverage(beverage) {}
};

class Espresso : public Beverage
{
    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return "Espresso";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

class Decaf : public Beverage
{
    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return "Decaf";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return 4;
    }
};

class CaramelDecorator : public CondimentDecorator
{
public:

    CaramelDecorator(Beverage& beverage) : CondimentDecorator(beverage) {}

    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetDescription() + " with Caramel";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetCost() + 2;
    }
};

class SoyDecorator : public CondimentDecorator
{
public:

    SoyDecorator(Beverage& beverage) : CondimentDecorator(beverage) {}

    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetDescription() + " with Soy";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetCost() + 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Decaf d;
    SoyDecorator s(d);
    CaramelDecorator c(s);
    CaramelDecorator cc(c);

    std::cout << cc.GetDescription() << std::endl;
    std::cout << cc.GetCost() << std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
Decaf with Soy with Caramel
7

// Expected:
// Decaf with Soy with Caramel with Caramel
// 9
```

Here is the same code but using pointers and works just fine:
https://ideone.com/7fpGSp

Comment: If you call `CaramelDecorator cc(c);` the (default) copy constructor is used. You may delete it to achieve what you intend. (I assume you don't need it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With switching from pointers to references, OPs constructor signature becomes very similar to the (default) copy constructor.

```
    CondimentDecorator(Beverage &beverage) : beverage(beverage) {}
```

vs.

```
    CondimentDecorator(const Beverage&); // generated by compiler
```

First, I assumed to delete the copy constructor would be sufficient but the compiler still tries to use the deleted constructor with a respective complaint as it cannot anymore.

Finally, I was able to fix OP's issue with providing the resp. candidates which prevent using the copy constructor.

(Deleting of copy constructor wasn't actually anymore needed but I left it in.)

```
class CondimentDecorator : public Beverage
{
public:

    Beverage& beverage;
    CondimentDecorator(Beverage &beverage) : beverage(beverage) {}
    CondimentDecorator(CondimentDecorator &beverage) : beverage(beverage) {}
    CondimentDecorator(const CondimentDecorator&) = delete;
};
```

The same has to be done for derived classes:

```
class CaramelDecorator : public CondimentDecorator
{
public:

    CaramelDecorator(Beverage &beverage) : CondimentDecorator(beverage) {}
    CaramelDecorator(CaramelDecorator &beverage) : CondimentDecorator(beverage) {}
    //CaramelDecorator(const CaramelDecorator&) = delete;

    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetDescription() + " with Caramel";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetCost() + 2;
    }
};
```

I fixed only the `CaramelDecorator` for demo but, actually, this has to be done for all derived classes of `class CondimentDecorator`.

The fixed MCVE of OP:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include "Decaf.h"
//#include "Espresso.h"
//#include "SoyDecorator.h"
//#include "CaramelDecorator.h"

class Beverage
{
public:
    virtual std::string GetDescription() const = 0;
    virtual int GetCost() const = 0;
};

class CondimentDecorator : public Beverage
{
public:

    Beverage& beverage;
    CondimentDecorator(Beverage &beverage) : beverage(beverage) {}
    CondimentDecorator(CondimentDecorator &beverage) : beverage(beverage) {}
    CondimentDecorator(const CondimentDecorator&) = delete;
};

class Espresso : public Beverage
{
    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return "Espresso";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return 5;
    }
};

class Decaf : public Beverage
{
    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return "Decaf";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return 4;
    }
};

class CaramelDecorator : public CondimentDecorator
{
public:

    CaramelDecorator(Beverage &beverage) : CondimentDecorator(beverage) {}
    CaramelDecorator(CaramelDecorator &beverage) : CondimentDecorator(beverage) {}
    //CaramelDecorator(const CaramelDecorator&) = delete;

    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetDescription() + " with Caramel";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetCost() + 2;
    }
};

class SoyDecorator : public CondimentDecorator
{
public:

    SoyDecorator(Beverage &beverage) : CondimentDecorator(beverage) {}

    virtual std::string GetDescription() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetDescription() + " with Soy";
    }

    virtual int GetCost() const override
    {
        return this->beverage.GetCost() + 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Decaf d;
    SoyDecorator s(d);
    CaramelDecorator c(s);
    CaramelDecorator cc(c);

    std::cout << cc.GetDescription() << std::endl;
    std::cout << cc.GetCost() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Decaf with Soy with Caramel with Caramel
9
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c9c1e508250fad7)

---

**Why the additional candidates are needed?**

`CondimentDecorator` is derived from `Beverage`.

So, for:

```
CondimentDecorator d;
CondimentDecorator d2(d);
```

the compiler has two choices to construct `d2`:

1. the custom constructor `CondimentDecorator::CondimentDecorator(Beverage &beverage)`
2. the (default) copy constructor `CondimentDecorator::CondimentDecorator(const CondimentDecorator&)`.

For the first, an implicit cast has to be applied but for the copy constructor, no cast is necessary (or at most, a const-cast).

Hence, the compiler prefers the copy constructor (unfortunately even, although it is deleted).

So, another candidate has to be provided which requires as less as implicit casts like the copy constructor:

3. another custom constructor `CondimentDecorator::CondimentDecorator(CondimentDecorator&)`.

Further reading: [**Overload Resolution**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution)